# If $P= \tan(3^{n+1}\theta) - \tan\theta$ and $ Q=\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{\sin(3^r\theta)}{\cos(3^{r+1}\theta)} $. Prove that $P=2Q$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I have been able to prove the above relation using the fact that $\tan{x}-\tan{y}$=$\frac{sin(x-y)}{cosx cosy}$. In my search for alternative solutions, I tried using the complex definition of sin and cos as in my mind it felt like a great start to generate a telescoping series. However, I was not able to simplify the expression when I took $sinx$ as $\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ and $cos3x$ as $\frac{e^{3ix}+e^{-3ix}}{2}$.

Please help me with how to prove this relation using complex numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it by using complex numbers but it is not necessary and probably more complicated than real version proof of Iab or robjohn.

Let $E_r=e^{3^r\theta i}$. Then we have $E_r^3=E_{r+1}$ and definition of trigonometric functions
$$Q=\frac1i\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{E_r-E_{r}^{-1}}{E_{r}^{3}+E_{r}^{-3}}\\
=\frac1{2i}\sum_{r=0}^n\left(\frac{E_{r}^{3}-E_{r}^{-3}}{E_{r}^{3}+E_{r}^{-3}}-\frac{E_r-E_{r}^{-1}}{E_{r}+E_{r}^{-1}}\right)
=\frac1{2i}\sum_{r=0}^n\left(\frac{E_{r+1}-E_{r+1}^{-1}}{E_{r+1}+E_{r+1}^{-1}}-\frac{E_r-E_{r}^{-1}}{E_{r}+E_{r}^{-1}}\right)
=\frac1{2i}\left(\frac{E_{n+1}-E_{n+1}^{-1}}{E_{n+1}+E_{n+1}^{-1}}-\frac{E_0-E_{0}^{-1}}{E_{0}+E_{0}^{-1}}\right)
=\frac12\left(\tan3^{n+1}\theta-\tan\theta\right)=\frac12 P
$$

Comment: Did you forget to write 2i in the second step? Also could you just  add one more step to justify your expansion, I feel it might benefit future readers. Just checked it myself using basic algebraic identities that the expansion simplifies out to get a term $2E_{r}(E_{r})^{-1}$ which yields 2.

Comment: @Rexquiem I am confused. I think it is ok now.

Comment: I referred to how you were able to expand the expression and generate a telescoping. Accepted the answer though, it was what I was looking for originally

Comment: @Rexquiem Thanks. I  now trying to solve this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4840198/221315 now with complex numbers or geometric. But I cant see anything.

Comment: I am unsure but I do feel like the idea of using vectors here.

Answer (score 4):

**Trigonometry**

Start with
$$
\begin{align}
\tan(3x)-\tan(x)
&=\frac{3\tan(x)-\tan^3(x)}{1-3\tan^2(x)}-\tan(x)\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac{2\tan(x)+2\tan^3(x)}{1-3\tan^2(x)}\tag{1b}\\
&=\frac{2\tan(x)\sec^2(x)}{1-3\tan^2(x)}\tag{1c}\\
&=\frac{2\tan(x)}{\cos^2(x)-3\sin^2(x)}\tag{1d}\\
&=\frac{2\tan(x)}{4\cos^2(x)-3}\tag{1e}\\
&=\frac{2\sin(x)}{4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)}\tag{1f}\\
&=\frac{2\sin(x)}{\cos(3x)}\tag{1g}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ $\tan(3x)=\frac{3\tan(x)-\tan^3(x)}{1-3\tan^2(x)}$
$\text{(1b):}$ simplify
$\text{(1c):}$ $\sec^2(x)=1+\tan^2(x)$
$\text{(1d):}$ multiply by $\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$
$\text{(1e):}$ $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$
$\text{(1f):}$ multiply by $\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x)}$
$\text{(1g):}$ $\cos(3x)=4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$

---

**De Moivre**

We can justify $\text{(1a)}$ by using [De Moivre's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula):
$$
\begin{align}
\overbrace{\cos(3x)(1+i\tan(3x))\vphantom{s^3}}^{\cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)}
&=\overbrace{\cos^3(x)(1+i\tan(x))^3}^{(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^3}\tag{2a}\\
&=\cos^3(x)\left(\left(1-3\tan^2(x)\right)+i\left(3\tan(x)-\tan^3(x)\right)\right)\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
Dividing the imaginary part of $(2)$ by the real part, yields $\text{(1a)}$.

We can also justify $\text{(1g)}$ by using De Moivre's Formula:
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(3x)+i\sin(3x)
&=(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))^3\tag{3a}\\
&=\left(4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)\right)+i\left(3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)\right)\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
The real part of $(3)$ gives $\text{(1g)}$.

---

**Telescoping Series**

Conclude with
$$
\begin{align}
\tan\left(3^nx\right)-\tan(x)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\tan\left(3^kx\right)-\tan\left(3^{k-1}x\right)\right)\tag{4a}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2\sin(3^{k-1}x)}{\cos(3^kx)}\tag{4b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a):}$ telescoping series
$\text{(4b):}$ sum $(1)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For $\sin t\cos t\ne0,$

$$\dfrac{\sin t}{\cos3t}=\dfrac{\sin t\cos t}{\cos t\cos3t}=\dfrac{\sin(3t-t)}{2\cos t\cos3t}= \dfrac{\tan3t-\tan t}2=f(1)-f(0)$$

where $f(m)=\dfrac{\tan3^mt}2$

Use [Telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)