# Showing $c^2+a^2= \csc^2\theta$, given $a^2+b^2+2ab \cos\theta=1$, $c^2+d^2+2cd \cos\theta=1$, $(ac+bd)+(ad+bc)\cos\theta=0$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

> Given that
> $$\begin{align}
> a^2+b^2+2ab \cos\theta &=1 \\
> c^2+d^2+2cd \cos\theta &=1 \\
> (ac+bd)+(ad+bc)\cos\theta &=0
> \end{align}$$
> Prove that $c^2+a^2 = \csc^2\theta$

I tried to solve this question by separating $\cos\theta$ in all the three equations, hoping to square it and then obtain $\csc^2\theta$. Got stuck.

Then I tried extracting $\cos\theta$ from the third equation, squaring it and finding $\csc^2\theta$ and somehow manipulating the first two equations to arrive at $c^2+a^2$. That failed too.

The equations somewhat resemble the cosine rule, but I just can't figure out how to manipulate them with so many variables involved.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to write equations On mathematics stack exchange,see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference   for quick reference, It is difficult to identiy second equation you wrote

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this website. Let me check what Mathjax is.

Comment: The second equation is c²+d²+2cdcosθ=1 and the third equation is (ac+bd) + (ad+bc)cosθ=0

Comment: You can brute force it by showing $ b =\pm  \sqrt{ 1 - a^2 \sin^2 \theta } - a\cos \theta$ from the first equation, and substituting that into the third equation to get an expression for $d$ in terms of $a, c$ only, then substituting that into the second equation to get an expressions involving $a, c$ only.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(1) is written as
$$(b + a\cos \theta)^2 = 1 - a^2 \sin^2\theta. \tag{4}$$

(2) is written as
$$(d + c\cos \theta)^2 = 1 - c^2 \sin^2 \theta. \tag{5}$$

(3) is written as
$$(b + a\cos \theta)(d + c\cos \theta) = - ac\sin^2\theta. \tag{6}$$

From (4)-(6), we have
$$(1 - a^2\sin^2\theta)(1 - c^2 \sin^2\theta) = a^2c^2 \sin^4\theta$$
which yields
$$c^2\sin^2\theta + a^2\sin^2\theta = 1.$$

We are done.

Comment: Thank you so much. An elegant solution indeed.

Comment: @DumbIdiot You are welcome.

Comment: Wow. So, somewhat surprisingly, we also have $(ad-bc)^2 \sin^2 \theta = 1$. This can be obtained by taking $(1) \times (2) - (3)^2 $.

Comment: @CalvinLin Nice. By the way, at first, I wanted to find a geometric method without success.